# Kickme Discord.js command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im trying to make a command that allows any user to `!kickme` which will obviously kick them. I would also like the command to send them a dm, im having issues getting started on the kickme part of it, i also cant quite figure out how to get it to dm the specific person that initiated the command, could someone point me in the right way? Below is my current code, although im not sure what good it will do

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')


module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const member = message.guild.member(user);
    message.member
}

}

  module.exports.help = {
    name: "kickme"
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to place commands in a file separate from the index.js file. Check out the Discord.js guide to command handling, https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/
It has a lot of useful information and in depth examples.

Comment: I am indeed trying to put a command file outside of my index(bot.js for me). im just trying to think of a way to configure it

Answer (score 0):

To message a user you would do this:
`message.author.send("you have been kicked")`
I would send this before kicking the user to simplify the coding process :)
also please ask for help on errors, trying using the docs or existing threads first